# Annotate the percent in barplot for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I made the following barplot using ggplot2 (if you run the code you will see everything) but instead of the count as annotation at the top of each bar I want the percent (this is easy) but for each year. If you run the following code you will understand what I mean.

For example I want in 2016 to see the percent of members and casuals (the sum of both to be 100%) If I just write label::percent etc. I will the percent as total of all years.

Thanks in advance

```
 library(reshape2)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(extrafont)

year = c(2016, 2017, 2018)
members = c(762017, 825130, 865997)
casual = c(275848, 366359, 268330)

df = data.frame(year, members, casual)
dfm <- melt(df, id=c("year"))


ggplot(dfm, aes(x = as.factor(year), y= value, fill = variable)) +
theme_minimal() +
geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.8, colour = 'black', position = "dodge", alpha = 0.8) +
labs(title = "Members vs Casual ", y = 'Percentage', x = "Year") +
geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("dodgerblue2", "red3")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=17, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black", face = 'bold')) +
theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = 8, family = 'Times New Roman')) +
theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size=13, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black", face = 'bold')) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 11, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black")) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black", face = 'bold')) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, family = 'Times New Roman', color = "black", face = 'bold')) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 900000, 100000)) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "gray30", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid") )+
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.6, "cm")) +
theme(legend.text=element_text(size=9), legend.spacing.x = unit(0.4, 'cm') ) +
theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=0.1, linetype="solid"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the percentages in your `dfm` line:

`dfm <- melt(df, id = c("year")) %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(value = value/sum(value))`

and then add `scales::percent` to your `geom_text` line

`geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value))`